# Windows Vista is booting with wrong drive letter

Tags: boot, windows-vista

Windows Vista is booting with wrong drive letter. Instead of booting with drive letter `C:`, it is getting drive letter `D:` and thus fails to login to a user profile.

This situation happened because I was trying to replace the hard drive:
I took out original hard drive from a computer containing Vista.
Put it into another computer and made a copy of the hard drive onto a new one using some partitioning GUI software.
I put the new hard drive back into the computer that had Vista on it.
When booting, it loads all the way to the login prompt.
When logging in, it hangs there for a while.
When pressing `Ctrl + Alt + Del`, I am able to launch Task Manager.
From Task Manager I start Explorer.exe.
It loads a temporary profile saying that it will be deleted upon log off.
Looking at the drive letters I see that it is assigned the wrong drive letter.

Start up repair from hard drive fails as RECOVERY partition is missing on this drive.

Tried Start up repair from Vista CD. It does not detect start up problems. The drive shows up correctly as `C:` in there.
Ran:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
chkdsk C: /f
```

That did not fix the problem.

Attempted to mess with the BIOS to disable other boot up items. That did not help.

No drive has `C:` assigned. OS drive gets `D:`. Memory card drives start with `E:` and below.

How do I fix the wrong letter assignment upon boot up into Vista?

**Solution**
Boot into safe mode by pressing F8 during boot.
Log into an account with Administrator privilege.
When "Preparing your desktop..." shows up, press `Ctrl + Alt + Del` and select Task Manager.
In Task Manager go to `File -> New Task (Run...)` and type in `explorer.exe`.
When Explorer loads follow the steps in the Answer to run regedt32.exe, rename devices, and reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Log on as an Administrator (or just run these as the Administrator)
2. Run `regedt32.exe`
3. Check if `Administrators` have full control over `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices` by right clicking on it and then clicking on `Permissions`
4. If you don't have `Full control` then select `Allow` to gain `Full control`
5. Run `regedit.exe`
6. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices`
7. Rename `\DosDevices\C:` to `\DosDevices\Z:`
8. Rename `\DosDevices\D:` to `\DosDevices\C:`
9. Rename `\DosDevices\Z:` to `\DosDevices\D:`
10. Reboot

Comment: Maybe you forget to mention 'reboot after these procedures'?

Comment: Updated my answer @iBug

Comment: I tried doing this from Vista DVD disk, but of course my drive is already C: when booting from DVD. I will have to see if I can somehow gain Admin privilege when booting from hard drive as the profile is not loading and many programs will not even run.

Comment: And by the way, I do not have anything as Drive C: when booting from hard drive.

Comment: I'm not able to gain Administrator privilege even though the user I am logging into is in an Administrator group. When logging in, it just hangs at "Preparing your desktop..." and does not get further than that. If I do start the task manager, it runs as unprivileged user.

Comment: I was able to gain Administrator privilege by booting into safe mode, logging into the user, when "Preparing your desktop..." shows up, Ctrl+Alt+Del and select Task Manager, File->New Task (Run...) and type in explorer. Then I was able to run regedt32 and did the rename as described above. For some strange reason there was an entry for C: drive, I confirmed via command line that there was no drive C:. After rebooting, I am able to login properly and OS drive is now C:.